# Deleting punctuation characters and entities from a text document

Tags: python

I need to delete the following punctuation characters and entities in a text document.

1. Delete `&#151`, `&#148`, `&#some number`
2. `; , . ( ) [ ] * ! !`
3. `&nbsp`

I know that I can use this to delete `&#some number` and `&nbsp`. However, as a beginner, I don't know if I can do the same thing to delete the other things like `;`, `,` etc.

```
match = re.sub(r'&#146', '', open('test2.txt', 'r').read())
```

Also, is there any way that I can delete all of them at once rather than running the same code so many times.

Comment: related: [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Those look like HTML and URL encoded entities.

You could just decode them using a variety of means

- urllib.unquote
- urllib.unquote_plus
- cgi.unescape
- http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml

Comment: Thanks. However, is there any way to delete , * ! . at once?

Comment: How about `re.sub(r"[][*!.();,]", "", your_string)`? Or, to take a slightly different approach, try matching everything but the characters you do want (such as letters, numbers and spaces): `re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "", your_string)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have everything in a string, you can simply use [`translate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
>>> s
"hello there ! this is a string with $ some % characters I & don't ( want!"
>>> s.translate(None,"$!%&(")
"hello there  this is a string with  some  characters I  don't  want"
```